# Scope error - (NameError: name 'date' is not defined)

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I'm trying to create a small widget that will calculate the notice of non-renewal date. Basically, subtract the notice of non-renewal days from the expiry date and generate an output by clicking on a button.

I get the following error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Abraham Valencia\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1699, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\Abraham Valencia\Desktop\Python Learning Folder\test1.py", line 50, in result
    result = datetime.date(date - days)
NameError: name 'date' is not defined
```

My code is as follows:

```
import tkinter as tk
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

class Application(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, master):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.master = master
        master.title("Trade Finance")
        master.minsize(width=250, height=200)
        master.maxsize(width=250, height=200)
        self.date = None


        #Input of expiry date
        label = tk.LabelFrame(master, text = "Input", bd = 2, font='none 8 italic')
        label.pack()
        tk.Label(label, text="Expiry Date (YYYY-MM-DD)",font = 'none 10').pack()

        self.userinput1 = tk.StringVar()
        tk.Entry(label,textvariable = self.userinput1).pack()

        #Input of non-renewal days
        tk.Label(label, text="Non-Renewal Days",font = 'none 10').pack()

        self.userinput2 = tk.StringVar()
        tk.Entry(label, textvariable = self.userinput2).pack()

        #output results
        label_1 = tk.LabelFrame(master, text = "Output", bd = 2, font='none 8 italic')
        label_1.pack()
        tk.Label(label_1,text= 'Review Date',font= 'none 10').pack()
        button = tk.Button(label_1, text="Calculate", fg ='white', bg = 'black',font= 'none 10 bold',command=self.result).pack()
        tk.Entry(label_1, textvariable = self.result).pack()


    def expiry(self):
        while True:
            date = self.userinput1.get()
            try:
                return datetime.strptime(date, '%Y-%m-%d')
            except ValueError:
                print('Please follow the date format')


    def notice_days(self):
        ndays = self.userinput2.get()
        return timedelta(days=ndays)

    def result(self):
        result = datetime.date(date - days)
        return result

if __name__=='__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = Application(root)
    app.mainloop()
```

Any idea on why I am having this type of error, or I'm I missing something that has not been declared properly. Thank you for the feedback.

Answer (score 0):

**Description of the problem:**

You declared date in method `expiry`.

By that, the date scope is the method `expiry`.

You try to access the date in method `result`, in this method you haven't declared date (the date from `expiry` method is in other scope than the `result` method).

**Solution:**

In order to fix that, you can make date variable a data-member of the class.

How to do it?

in `__init__` method declare on date:

```
self.data = None
```

In `expiry` method use it like this:

```
self.date = self.userinput1.get()
```

In method `result`:

```
if self.date:
    result = datetime.date(self.date - days)
```

I would recommend you to read about python scopes in [here](http://python-textbok.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/Variables_and_Scope.html)

Comment: Thank you @omri_saadon. I have followed your feedback which makes sense. My code runs with no errors but once I press the button nothing is showing up in the output label. Do you know why?

Comment: @AbrahamValencia , That's because you need to return the result in `result` method. add another line in `result` method: `return result`

Comment: result continues to show nothing. I have included in the above code your feedback.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use self.date in the `result` function:

```
def result(self):
    result = datetime.date(self.date - days)
    return result
```

However, this will still throw an error because:

a) `self.date` is initialized to None and never changed to a number

b) `days` is not defined (and I see no reference to it elsewhere in the code).

What is the expected behavior of this code?